# How can I obtain relevant params, classes, and methods from a .groovy script from Java?

Tags: java, groovy

I have a Java plugin for a larger application that does image analysis using the ImageJ library. One client who switched to our software has been using Groovy scripts to define specific rules and parameters for when they perform the analysis in ImageJ. They would like our software to be able to accept the Groovy scripts as well, as they'll be working within our GUI as well as ImageJ.

They will provide a written script.groovy to the plugin, but I won't always know exactly what parameters, methods, and classes are present and what changes to the logic are in the .groovy file.

I've been looking into the `GroovyClassLoader` documentation, and after referencing *Groovy in Action, 2nd Edition* I have a better idea of how to create and send bindings and whatnot but I can't figure out where to start writing the logic for interpreting the contents of a static Groovy file. An ideal solution would be the user having one script that works in both programs, and my plugin determines what is relevant.

Is there any way to parse out individual parts of a Groovy file so that I might map them to our parameters and change the Java plugin's behavior accordingly?

**Edit: Context**

Our software performs real-time image analysis on stained tissue slides. Some of our users also use "Program X" within its GUI to perform analysis on images that have already been taken. The Java plugin accesses the logic from the other program, allowing our users to use features they're familiar with in real-time.
The Groovy script `file.groovy` that the user gives to Program X has some functions that feed data to the UI portions of the software that we don't need. I'd like to only parse our relevant portions of the script.

**Edit: Sample File, and what I'd like to parse:**

The .groovy file begins with some parameters, which are no use to me, as well as some methods for defining image background, also no use as my program does this automatically, where "Program X" does not:

```
/* imports */
//PARAMETER AREA//

//PARAMETERS FOR IMAGES WITH UM//
double requested_pixel_size = 0.5
double background_radius = 8
double median_filter_radius = 0
double sigma = 1.5
double minimum_area = 10
double maximum_area = 400
double threshold = 0.1
//PARAMETER AREA ENDS//

def openingReconstruction(final ImageProcessor ip, final ImageProcessor ipBackground, final double radius, final double maxBackground) {
    final RankFilters rf = new RankFilters()
    ipBackground.setRoi(ip.getRoi())
    rf.rank(ipBackground, radius, RankFilters.MIN)
    ByteProcessor bpMask = null
    if (!Double.isNaN(maxBackground) && maxBackground > 0) {
        int w = ip.getWidth()
        int h = ip.getHeight()
        for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
            if (ipBackground.getf(i) > maxBackground) {
                if (bpMask == null)
                    bpMask = new ByteProcessor(w, h)
                bpMask.setf(i, 1f)
            }
        }
        if (bpMask != null) {
            rf.rank(bpMask, radius * 2, RankFilters.MAX)
            for (int i = 0; i < w * h; i++) {
                if (bpMask.getf(i) != 0f) {
                    ipBackground.setf(i, Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then there are some area which actually enhance our program, and I need to be able to implement:

```
def detect(double key_value, PathObject parentObject, int Choose_detection_image, ParameterList params) {
    def viewer = QPEx.getCurrentViewer()
    ImageData<BufferedImage> imageData = viewer.getImageData()
    println("Program starts.....")
```

The above code snippet will eventually call a modified version of the detection class which I need:

```
detect(key_value, parentObject, Choose_detection_image, params)

class WatershedCellDetection2 {
    protected ObjectDetector<BufferedImage> createDetector(ImageData<BufferedImage> imageData, ParameterList params, double key_value) {
        ObjectDetector<BufferedImage> detector = new NewCellDetector(key_value)
//insert the key_value in original detector.
        return new DetectorWrapper<>(detector)
    }
```

There are a few overloaded methods and other versions of the `WatershedCellDetection` that are used depending on what parameters are present, but as long as I know how to parse out one I can determine which one is best for each scenario.

There is a lot of code built into the functions that do things like update the help text in the GUI of "Program X" that are irrelevant to my program's UI since this is all interacting with a Java plugin of a C# program.

Comment: You have to look at http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html

Comment: And I can't understand why do you need to know what params and methods in script. Just call script (as a function) pass there binding variables, and get a result (if needed).

Comment: Not 100% understanding the use case, but I think you'll need to agree on an interface that allows the script to inform your plugin of what it's doing. Then this can either be injected into the script binding for them to call, or their scripts could implement the interface for you to call... Or maybe a custom script base class like here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html#_custom_script_class but if it's you and a third party, something formal might be better

Comment: @daggett Updated question for context. The script.groovy file has many methods that alter the GUI of Program X which aren't relevant to my program. There are however, a few functions that make some big changes to the logic of the algorithms being run. The script in its entirety utilizes *some* imports that are irrelevant to my program.

Comment: @sentientflesh, your approach is wrong. You can't parse part of script. If script contains some methods you need to call then you have to parse script and run required method. Or run script and take result and/or binding variables changed in script.

Comment: @daggett Thank you. I had some misunderstanding of Groovy verbiage. I'm receiving some `file.groovy` which contains classes and variables. I did not realize that in this context a Groovy **file** is not synonymous with a Groovy **script**. This should help me determine a better course of action.

Comment: Show the sample of your file and what do you want to access.

Comment: @SentientFlesh If you are interested in top-level bindings in a Groovy file/script, then parse the file via `Script s = GroovyShell.parse()` and access the variables via `s.binding`.  If you are interested in the values of top-level bindings, then execute the script via `s.run()` and access the bindings via `s.binding` property.  If you are interested in the classes and top-level methods, then access them via `s.class.classLoader.loadedClasses` and `s.methods` after parsing the file.

Comment: @Venkatesh-PrasadRanganath This is the approach I am looking at now, I'm just trying to figure out the nuance of bindings, as some methods are irrelevant, some are needed, and some contain variables that are irrelevant along with portions that are. But at least the core methods that can be altered by the script are limited to less than a dozen, so that gives me some starting place for looking for types.